# How do i center div to BODY not It's parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a sticky Main menu with the tab "categories" that drops down the menu "categoriesDropdown" when i hover the mouse over it.

- I need the dropdown menu to have the width of the screen, and be
  centered in the screen.
- I need the dropdown menu to stick to the bottom of the Main Menu.

The only problem is that i can't seem to center the dropdown menu to the body. I can only place it relative to the parent div (categories)
The code i use is showed under.

```
<div class="categories">
   <a>Categories</a>
   <div id="categoriesDropdown"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.categories {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#categoriesDropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1d1d1d;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: auto;
}

#categoriesDropdown.show {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Edit: This happens when i try left: 0; right: 0; [the grey square being the drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aei8X.png)

Comment: If i'm understanding right all you should have to do is put left:0 and right :0 on your #categoriesDropdown to center it verically and you can use top:0 and bottom:0 to center vertically if needed

Comment: That centers it in the middle of the categories div. My question is how i can center it in the middle of the body.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky with only CSS, but here is possible solution with jQuery and css. I am not sure this will help's you or not.

Body

```
<div class="categories">
  <a>Categories</a>
  <div id="categoriesDropdown" class="categoriesDropdown">  </div>
```

Css

```
body{
  margin : 0px;
  padding : 0px;
  }
  .categories {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor : pointer;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  }
  .categoriesDropdown {
  position: relative;
  background: #1d1d1d;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 0px;
  z-index:-1;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  color:#fff;
  }
  .categoriesDropdown_show {
  height: 100px;
  }
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var c = $(".categories");
  var position = c.position();

     $(".categories").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#categoriesDropdown").appendTo('body');
         $(".categoriesDropdown").addClass("categoriesDropdown_show");
         $('#categoriesDropdown').css({'top':'calc('+position.top +'px + 20px)'});
     });
     $(".categories").mouseleave(function(){
         $(".categoriesDropdown").removeClass("categoriesDropdown_show");
         $("#categoriesDropdown").appendTo('categories');
     });
  });
```

Comment: You can also declare var for class 'categories' instead of '20px' height. //$('#categoriesDropdown').css({'top':'calc('+position.top +'px + 20px)'});
             var h = c.height();
             $('#categoriesDropdown').css({'top':'calc('+position.top +'px + '+ h +'px)'});